# Selecting some rows of an nparray under column constraints

Tags: python, numpy

I have two nparrays

`A` of dimensions (60000,784)

and

`B` of dimensions (60000, 1)

they both store integers.

I would like to create an nparray that contains rows from `A` such that the corresponding row of `B` is either some number X or some number Y. I would also want to return a second nparray that contains the corresponding rows of `B`.

Example:

```
A

1 2
3 4
5 6
8 9


B

2
5
6
1
```

suppose that I want the rows of A such that the corresponding row of B is either 1 or 5. Then the first nparray returned will be the following:

```
3 4
8 9
```

and the second nparray will be the following:

```
5
1
```

is something like this possible with nparrays?

thank you in advance

Comment: Please can you add a *small* example showing `A` and `B` and your expected output?

Comment: I just added a small example. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.in1d` to create a boolean index.

```
A = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [8, 9]])
B = np.array([2,5,6,1])

index = np.in1d(B, [1,5])

print A[index]

print B[index]
```

Comment: For only two values for `x` and `y`, `index = (B==x) | (B==y)` is much faster (though the difference decreases for very large `B`).

Comment: @askewchan what is the order of time differences? I always see these kinds of comments but I am not sure if people are talking absolute time or relative time. Is it microseconds or seconds?

Comment: Hi @Dan, I was speaking relatively: the `or` is 6 times faster than the `in1d` for the example arrays given, but that's clearly not a good test case. On random arrays of the sizes in the question (60k), it is only about 50% faster. Of course, absolute times are hard to compare, but on my computer we are talking milliseconds. Looking more closely, the slowest part is actually _using_ the boolean index: `A[index]` takes 100 ms :P In fact, in numpy, fancy indexing is often the slowest thing I see, despite fancy algorithms elsewhere. But micro-improvements are fun!